# Continuity of point wise orientation

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, orientation

Prove that $[(X_1,...,X_n)]$ on a manifold $M$ is continuous if and only if every point $p$ in $M$ has a coordinate neighborhood $(U,\phi) = (U,x^1,...,x^n)$ such that for all $ q \in U$, the differential $ \phi_{ \ast,q}: T_qM \to T_{f(q)}\mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{R}^n $ carries the orientation of $T_qM$ to the stander orientation of $\mathbb{R}^n $ in the following sense: $(\phi_{ \ast}X_{1,q},..., \phi_{ \ast}X_{n,q}) \sim (\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1},..., \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n})$

How can i prove this, this exercise is from Introduction to Manifolds Tu,Thanks for your help, I try but really I stuck in this problem.

Comment: Some help please!!!!

Comment: Did you happen to get this already Knight? I think this has something to do with 1. Proposition 8.8 which says $\phi_{ \ast}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_{q} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r^i}|_{q}$ 2. the orientation is actually locally $X_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ or something 3. Lemma 21.4 which says continuity is equivalent to the existence of a coordinate neighborhood where $dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n(X_1, ..., X_n) > 0$ on the neighborhood. My guess is that the neighbor in the exercise is the same as the neighborhood in Lemma 21.4.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to verify that $$(\mathrm{d}r^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}r^n)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1},\cdots, \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n}\right)=1>0.$$
By Lemma 21.1, $(\phi_* X_{1,q},\cdots, \phi_* X_{n,q})\sim \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1},\cdots, \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n}\right)$ is equivalent to
$$(\mathrm{d}r^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}r^n) (\phi_* X_{1,q},\cdots, \phi_* X_{n,q})= (\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^n)(X_{1,q},\cdots,X_{n,q})>0,$$
which is equivalent that $[(X_1,\cdots,X_n)]$ is continuous on $M$ by lemma 21.4.