# Verify proof for continuity of pointwise orientation

Tags: general-topology, geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds

This has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544907/continuity-of-point-wise-orientation), but there is no answer.

> Prove that $[(X_1,...,X_n)]$ on a manifold $M$ is continuous if and only if every point $p$ in $M$ has a coordinate neighborhood $(U,\phi) = (U,x^1,...,x^n)$ such that for all $ q \in U$, the differential $ \phi_{ \ast,q}: T_qM \to T_{f(q)}\mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{R}^n $ carries the orientation of $T_qM$ to the stander orientation of $\mathbb{R}^n $ in the following sense: $(\phi_{ \ast}X_{1,q},..., \phi_{ \ast}X_{n,q}) \sim (\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1},..., \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n})$

- This is an [exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf0x8.png) from An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu, but are there some mistakes? I think:

  1. $\color{red}{\phi(q)}$ and not $f(q)$ in "$T_qM \to T_{f(q)}\mathbb{R}$"
  2. $(\phi_{ \ast}X_{1,q},..., \phi_{ \ast}X_{n,q}) \sim (\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1}\color{red}{\mid_{\phi(q)}},..., \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n}\color{red}{\mid_{\phi(q)}})$

**Here is my proof: What is the correct proof if I am wrong?**

$\rightarrow$

I'm not sure continuity is needed here. A pointwise orientation is a frame and so $X_{1,q},..., X_{n,q}$ is an ordered basis for $T_qU \cong T_qM$, by [Remark 8.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlUw8.png). The $(U,\phi)$ in question is the same as the one in [Lemma 21.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvkNy.png). Since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism by [Proposition 6.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2nmB.png), $\phi_{ \ast}$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces by [Corollary 8.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NIaP.png) and so carries basis element to basis element.

- Perhaps this is wrong because I am supposed

  1. to deduce that locally $X_{1,q} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\mid_{q}$, perhaps with Proposition 8.9, something like what was done in the [proofs of Theorem 21.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ye1W.png) or [Theorem 21.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bJhc.png)
  2. to somehow use [Proposition 8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sul1D.png).
  3. to somehow use to the $dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n (X_1, ..., X_n) > 0$ on $U$ from [Lemma 21.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvkNy.png)

$\leftarrow$

Again, without continuity assumed (all the more relevant because continuity is what we're trying to prove this time), a pointwise orientation is a frame and so $X_{1,q},..., X_{n,q}$ is an ordered basis for $T_qU \cong T_qM$, by [Remark 8.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlUw8.png).

Again, $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism by [Proposition 6.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2nmB.png), $\phi_{ \ast}$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces by [Corollary 8.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NIaP.png) and so carries basis element to basis element.

The $\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1}\color{red}{\mid_{\phi(q)}},..., \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n}\color{red}{\mid_{\phi(q)}}$ are smooth and so by assumption of equivalence, the $\phi_{ \ast}X_{1,q},..., \phi_{ \ast}X_{n,q}$ are smooth. Since $\phi_{ \ast}$ is an isomorphism, I guess the $(X_{1,q},...,X_{n,q})$ are smooth and thus continuous.

- The last part might be wrong because I assume smoothness is preserved under a vector space isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

A pointwise orientation is not a frame but rather a equivalence class of of (possible discontinous) frames, where two frames are equivalent iff at each point the corresponding ordered bases are equivalent.

Furthermore if a pointwise orientation is continous on $U$ then this just means one can  find a frame which is continous on $U$ and represents the pointwise orientation. So for example even if 
$(\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1},\dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n})$ is continous and $(\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1},\dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n})\sim (\phi_{ \ast}X_{1},\dots, \phi_{ \ast}X_n)$ on $\phi(U)$ this does not necessarily imply that $(\phi_{ \ast}X_{1},\dots, \phi_{ \ast}X_n)$ is continous.

But i think the approach of using Lemma 21.4 is good:

Set $\beta=dr^1\wedge\dots\wedge dr^n$. Then

> 1. $\beta(\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1}|_{\phi(q)},\dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n}|_{\phi(q)})=1$
> 2. $\beta(\phi_{ \ast}X_{1,q},\dots, \phi_{ \ast}X_{n,q})=dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n(X_{1,q},\dots,X_{n,q})$

Now by 1., 2. and the corollary of Lemma 21.1  $(\phi_{ \ast}X_{1,q},\dots, \phi_{ \ast}X_{n,q}) \sim (\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1}|_{\phi(q)},\dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial r^n}|_{\phi(q)})$ is equivalent  to $dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n(X_{1,q},\dots,X_{n,q})>0$ and hence we can apply Lemma 21.4 to prove the desired equivalence.

Comment: Hi. I know this question is a bit old but I want to ask, you said : "A pointwise orientation is not a frame but rather a equivalence class of of (possible discontinous) frames, where two frames are equivalent iff at each point the corresponding ordered bases are equivalent." So I just want to clarify, are we assuming that these are global frames and not local frames?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!